# Remove if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ramda.js

If if statement could be avoided it is considered a good practice.

For example this code:

```
if (a > 80) {
  a = 80;
}
```

Can become this:

```
a = Math.min(80, a);
```

That way the code is considered cleaner because there is no branch logic.

But is there any way to avoid if for more complex problems like this:

```
if (array.length > 5) {
   array = array.reverse().join('');
} else {
   array = 'array is lte 5';
}
```

If array length is > 5 then reverse it and join it, otherwise return "array is lte 5".

This is simple example but more complex than the first example and it's hard to remove if.

How mathematics handle branches and is it possible to express this logic in mathematics.

I can extract it to a separate method but it will only move the if statement in the method itself, it will not remove it.

I can imagine I can use some functions from Ramdajs but i didn't find appropriate one and even if I find one the if will be there i guess - it will be only abstracted.

Also imagine this sudo code:

```
if (file_exists(file)) {
   content = file_read(file);
   if (content.startsWith('config')) {
       ret = 'config:'; 
   } else if (content.endsWith(':app')) {
       ret = ':app';
   }  
} else {  
   ret = '';
}
```

This code has only 2 if statements but already is a nightmare to read and change.

Is it possible to use mathematic and/or express it more clearly avoiding branches.

I know in mathematics there is no "read file" but it was just an example.

Thank you

Comment: Although this is an interesting question - therefore I voted it up -, I don't think this is a _good_ question in a sense that besides of philosophical value it helps you writing better code. There is no contest of writing the code with the least amount of if statements.

Comment: And you think `Math.min()` has no branch logic? Also, you can always use `?` `:` for more concise code: `array = array.length > 5 ? array.reverse().join('') : 'array is lte 5';`

Comment: Thanks, that is correct, i dont say "ifs" are bad but if we manage to write more readable code it would be better.

Comment: @niry, yes but in the last example it would be very hard to read: a ? (b ? (c ? d :f ) : f and it would be more readable with if's i think when you have more than 1 if statements.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to put the thing you need to operate on in a "box" on which you apply a series of operations (i.e. functions). This forces you to remove any nested conditions.

This pseudo-code:

```
if (file_exists(file)) {
   content = file_read(file);
   if (content.startsWith('config')) {
       ret = 'config:'; 
   } else if (content.endsWith(':app')) {
       ret = ':app';
   }  
} else {  
   ret = '';
}
```

could be replaced with:

```
const ret =
  [file]
    .map(x => file_exists(x) ? file_read(x) : '')
    .map(x => x.startsWith('config') ? 'config:' : x)
    .map(x => x.endsWith(':app') ? ':app' : x)
    .pop();
```

Note that the above could we converted using function composition:

```js
const ret =
  pipe(
    ifElse(file_exists, file_read, always('')),
    when(startsWith('config'), always('config:')),
    when(endsWith(':app'), always(':app')))
      (file)
```

Of course one could argue that you execute unnecessary checks but unless a performance issue has been identified, I'd always favour readability over anything else.

Can we improve readability here? We certainly can try:

```js
const ret =
  [file]
    .map(load_file_content)
    .map(when_starts_with('config'))
    .map(when_ends_with(':app'))
    .pop();
```

Or

```js
const ret =
  pipe(
    load_file_content,
    when_starts_with('config'),
    when_ends_with(':app'))
      (file)
```

I find this readable but others may not so ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Besides the ternary operator (which probably isn't gonna make things more legible), have you considered early returns?

```
if (!file_exists(file)) {
    return '';
}

content = file_read(file);
if (content.startsWith('config')) {
    return 'config:'; 
}
if (content.endsWith(':app')) {
    return ':app';
}

return ...;
```

There's still gonna be just as much branching logic behind the scenes, but this way you can logically unentangle semantically different code blocks from each other.

Comment: That's more readable but some say that multiple return statements are considered bad practice because each function should have one exit point, but others say the opposite.

Comment: A single exit point gives you absolutely nothing in terms of mental model-ability. In languages where you have to do resource management and have no construct like Java's `finally` available, that's a different story, and there I could loosely suggest a `do {} while(false)` loop with `break` instead and have the cleanup code after that loop. But other than that, early exits actually make for _great_ mental models. You first get rid of all the annoying stuff that can go wrong, and then focus on what you _actually_ want to do.